# PostAsJsonAsync doesn't send call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a windows forms application that calls a WebAPI that I wrote.  In the application I have the following code

```
log.Info("Starting Search...");
string SearchURL = DatabaseConnection.BaseURL + "/api/v3/internal/WireSearch";
WireSearchRequest Request = new WireSearchRequest() { AuthKey = AuthKey, SearchString = SearchTextBox.Text };
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
log.Info("Search 1...");
var task = Client.PostAsJsonAsync(SearchURL, Request);
log.Info("Search 1a...");
task.Wait();
log.Info("Search 1b...");
var Response = task.Result;
log.Info("Search 2...");
```

This code works perfectly on every computer except on the one that the person who is using the program is using.  In the log I get:

```
INFO  2013-11-27 16:31:41 [SearchButton_Click] - Starting Search...
INFO  2013-11-27 16:31:41 [SearchButton_Click] - Search 1...
INFO  2013-11-27 16:31:41 [SearchButton_Click] - Search 1a...
```

I realize that the UI is frozen by this but I am fine with that for the time being as the service returns in about .250 seconds.  It is a windows 8 machine and I am using .NET framework 4.0

When I create a simple form as a html page to post the values it returns very quickly.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would not be working?

Thanks

Comment: Something at the network at HTTP layer is taking a lot of time. Use Fiddler to find out.

Comment: Are you sure it's not sending your request (use Fiddler), or are you running in a Task deadlock?

Comment: I am not able to install Fiddler on this particular Machine.  I know that the web server is not getting the request as I can see the IIS logs.

Comment: Set the timeout to 1s to confirm that you are getting a timeout exception. If yes, some network thing is the problem. If no, you are deadlocking (no response will ever arrive).